# How to get content from URL asynchronously?

Tags: objective-c, macos, asynchronous

I'm trying here to create `NSXMLParser` from content of URL, it work perfectly well but is there way I can make URL content to be received asynchronously and later create `NSXMLParser`?

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://www.Xmlfile.com"];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[url release];
```

Comment: complete example is posted here http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/jack-cox/tutorial-simple-iphone-rest-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to fetch the data asynchronously into an NSData, then use [initWithData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of initWithContentsOfURL.